# Identifying End-Of-Line in Regular expressions in R

Tags: regex, r, tweets

I wrote a small code to extract hashtags from tweets in R

```
m<-c(paste("Hello! #London is gr8. #Wow"," ")) # My tweet
#m<- c("Hello! #London is gr8. #Wow")

x<- unlist(gregexpr("#(\\S+)",m))
#substring(m,x)[1]

subs<-function(x){
  return(substring(m,x+1,(x-2+regexpr(" |\\n",substring(m,x)[1]))))
}

tag<- sapply(x, subs)
#x
tag
```

This code didn't work without my appending the space at the end of the tweet. What could be the reason? I tried \n as well.

Comment: did you try putting  $ in front?

Comment: Yes. That will cause a prob hashtags in the middle of the tweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` matches the end of a string.

```
m<- c("Hello! #London is gr8. #Wow")

subs<-function(x){
  return(substring(m,x+1,(x-2+regexpr(" |$",substring(m,x)[1]))))
}
```

With the rest of your code intact:

```
> tag
[1] "London" "Wow"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `gregexpr` gives you the information you need:

```
R> m<- c("Hello! #London is gr8. #Wow")
R> (x<- gregexpr("#(\\S+)",m)[[1]])
[1]  8 24
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 7 4
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

So we can just combine the `match.length` with the starting position:

```
R> substring(m, x+1 , x - 1 + attr(x,"match.length"))
[1] "London" "Wow"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
m <- c("Hello! #London is gr8. #Wow")
x <- unlist(strsplit(m, " "))
tag <- x[grep("^#", x)]
tag
```

Now, let's imagine you have a list of tweets, like this one:

```
m1 <- c("Hello! #London is gr8. #Wow")
m2 <- c("#Hello! #London is gr8. #Wow")
m3 <- c("#Hello! #London i#s gr8. #Wow")
m4 <- c("Hello! #London is gr8. #Wow ")
m <- list(m1, m2, m3, m4)
```

You can write a small function:

```
getTags <- function(tweet) {
  x <- unlist(strsplit(tweet, " "))
  tag <- x[grep("^#", x)]
  return(tag)
}
```

and apply it:

```
lapply(m, function(tweet) getTags(tweet))
[[1]]
[1] "#London" "#Wow"   
[[2]]
[1] "#Hello!" "#London" "#Wow"   
[[3]]
[1] "#Hello!" "#London" "#Wow"   
[[4]]
[1] "#London" "#Wow"
```

An afterthought...

If you want the hash (or any punctuation to be removed) the function should be

```
getTags <- function(tweet) {
  x <- unlist(strsplit(tweet, " "))
  tag <- x[grep("^#", x)]
  tag <- gsub("#", "", tag)
  return(tag)
}
```

or

```
getTags <- function(tweet) {
  x <- unlist(strsplit(tweet, " "))
  tag <- x[grep("^#", x)]
  tag <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", tag)
  return(tag)
}
```